# Symfony 3.4 - Doctrine many-to-one returns the Object ID but not the Object itself

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Since last week I have started learning Symfony, and while the general stuff it quite easy to learn, the Doctrine seems to be a big pain.

Currently, I have made two entities using the following signature:

```
<?php

namespace NutritionApiBundle\Entity;

// ...
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
// ...

/**
 * Company
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 *     @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="NutritionApiBundle\Repository\CompanyRepository")
 */
class Company {
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NutritionApiBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="company")
     */
    protected $products;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

and

```
<?php
namespace NutritionApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
// ...

/**
 * Class Product
 *
 * @package NutritionApiBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product {
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * @var Company
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid", name="company", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NutritionApiBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $company;

    // ...

    /**
     * Return the product company
     *
     * @return Company
     */
    public function getCompany() {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * Set the product company.
     *
     * @param Company $company
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCompany( Company $company ) {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But when I try to execute the following code:

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class)->findOneBy(['id' => '0642d735-fcfd-11e7-afae-0242c0a86002']);

return $this->render( '@NutritionApi/Default/index.html.twig', [ 'product' => $product ] );
```

And inside the `index.html.twig` I have this code:

```
{{ dump(product.company) }}
```

The output is the following:

```
"e65af24f-fd0a-11e7-afae-0242c0a86002"
```

While I need the full company object as output.

Do you see anything wrong with my code? I have read my code and my annotations multiple times in order to spot a mistake but I cannot find anything.

The only thing that I guess it could be the problem is the `GUID` id I use for the entities in my DB, but I am not sure this is the problem.

Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to remove

```
@ORM\Column(type="guid", name="company", nullable=false)
```

From Product $company property.

Comment: I agree. Because `@ORM\Column(type="guid", name="company", nullable=false)` define the column as a simple `guid` column. The `ManyToOne` column will refer to the id of the company, whatever its type is

Comment: That should solve the problem joinColumn is not needed as well

Comment: And the column `company` should be of what type? Or you mean I should remove the whole column?

Comment: I just changed the column signature to this: `* @ORM\Column(type="string", name="company", nullable=false)` but still getting the same output. Please note, that I have done the `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` and the command executed succesfully.

Comment: No type needed, just the ManyToOne annotation. Doctrine will map it to the Company id (guid defined in Company entity)

In Product:
`/**
     * @var Company
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NutritionApiBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="products")
     */
    protected $company;
`